# Vue with CDN - best way to style components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm importing Vue to my project through CDN. I have components in .js files such as sample.js:

```
var sample = {
template: `
    <div>
        <p>sample component</p>
    </div>
`
};
```

Then I import it in my index.html and use it in my app. I would now like to apply styles just to the component just like I would if I used Vue through NPM or CLI.
If that is not possible what is the best alternative?

Comment: well, using `Single File Component (SFC)` along with `scoped css` instead. That snippet reminds me yuck react.

Comment: @SCKim I don't think that's possible when using Vue through CDN and not Webpack.

Comment: Right, What a bummer. I guess only global css class styling for those templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add style in Vue js 3 on a cdn based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297857/how-to-add-style-in-vue-js-3-on-a-cdn-based-app)