# How to add style in Vue js 3 on a cdn based app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm learning Vue js. I created an app with Vue included from a CDN and I want to know how to add a `<style>` to it.

I can write template as `` template: `<div>Vue js 3</div>` ``  but can a `"style": " ... "` string be written added to the component JS in the same way?

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
  },
  template: `<button @click="increment">count is: {{ count }}</button>`,
  // can style be written like the template above? For example, I tried:
  style: {
    button {
      background: red;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(`The initial count is ${this.count}.`)
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your component link? Do you want to code single file component?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you.

```
 <style>
  @import './yourStyles.css';
 </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

If styles is particular to this component button, then you can use `scoped` style.

```
<style scoped>
  button {
    background : red;
  }
</style>
```

If you want to apply common style for all the `buttons` in an application then you can create a common style file and then import wherever you want to access.

```
<style>
  @import './button.css';
</style>
```

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    }
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">count is: {{ count }}</button>
</div>
```